# How can I achieve a 2 column layout with bootstrap in a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, themes

This is the problem I am experiencing...I cannot get the content to lay in 2 columns..they start stacking vertically.[enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/teAWT.jpg

Comment: 1) It's not WordPress question. 2) It's too specific for Stack Overflow. You should make your problem more general, and provide specific examples so we can reproduce and answer.

Answer (score 2):

col-md-6 in bootstrap means that you will have only one column. This can fix firstly (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

If you change this you can use display flex to put elements correctly (cool guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Last issue, the browser window can be too small to check this. Try to make it bigger ;)